# Dart DevTools - build/ios-code-size-analysis_01.json can not be drag & dropped

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

First I run  `flutter build ios  --analyze-size`.
Then I try to drag & drop the build/ios-code-size-analysis_01.json file into the already open Dart DevTools "Analyze size" window.

Expected behavior: The file is accepted and analyzed.

Actual behavior: I can´t drop the file.

Possible problem: To open DevTools I run the App on a simulated iPhone as I own no real iPhone. But even through the "Open App size tooling" Button the actual behavior persists.
Other possible problem: When opening the build/ios-code-size-analysis_01.json file android studio gives a "The file size (10.65MB) exceeds configured limit (2.56MB). Code insight features  are not available" & "This document contains very long lines. Soft wraps were forcibly enabled to improve editor performance".

Any idea what I could do different to analyze the size of the app components?